# The correct use of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, code-snippets

I was working on a project solely made of js and I wanted to test my array skills cuz I was getting rusty so I used this code arrays to print string 1, string 2, string 3 to my console but it printed with the brackets. Do i need to insert the `() and =>`signs or make use of `return`, before logging it to my console? Not an urgent question, I just need clarification.

```js
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
console.log(hobbies)
```

Comment: What exactly would you expect instead? `string 1, string 2, string 3`?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `console.log(...hobbies)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach method to get each element

```
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
hobbies.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

You were logging the whole array at once. What you want to achieve can be done by iterating over the array and log each string inside it one by one.

```js
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
hobbies.forEach(s => console.log(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log each string, you will need to console.log each string individually. console.log the array itself will show you an array.

```js
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']

hobbies.forEach( str => console.log(str) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'];
console.log(hobbies.join());
// you can also modify the union char (default ',')
console.log(hobbies.join(' - '));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the each value of the array, you need to go thought it and call the `console.log` function.

There is multiple method allowing you to go though an array.

The most oldest one, using `for()`, like :

```js
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'];

for (let i = 0; i < hobbies.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(hobbies[i]);
}
```

New method, using `Array.forEach` function :

```js
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'];

hobbies.forEach(function (x) {
   console.log(x);
});

hobbies.forEach((x) => {
   console.log(x);
});
```

The `() =>` syntax is called an **arrow function** ; I let you checkout out google about it. In the upper snippet, you can see that both `function` and `() =>` syntaxes, leads to the same result.

---

Alternatives ways to display the content of the array :

```js
const hobbies = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'];

// We simply removed the { }. It's possible to do so using arrow functions
hobbies.forEach(x => console.log(x));

// We use here the "spread operator"
console.log(...hobbies);

// Equivalence of the spread operator syntax:
// console.log(hobbies[0], hobbies[1], hobbies[2]);

console.log(hobbies.join(' '));
```

---

**Recommandation** :

The use of one or another depends on your use case ; but I can safely say that you use either `Array.forEach` or the **spread operator** (depending if you want newlines or not).